# How to use SFML Textures as static data members?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm writing Space Invaders in c++ using SFML. My plan is to load the texture of the bullet only once and then use it for every sprite. Thus I've started learning about static data members, but I don't know how to load the texture.

I've tried declaring the data member inside the class and then loading outside

```
class Lovedek
{
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    static sf::Texture texture;
};

sf::Texture Lovedek::texture.loadFromFile("bullet_graphics.png",sf::IntRect(0, 0, 2, 10));
```

It keeps saying `error: expected initializer before '.' token`.

Now I know that I'm supposed to be using a =operator, but I can't load with that.
Or if anyone knows a better way to load only once, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sf::Texture Lovedek::texture.loadFromFile("bullet_graphics.png",sf::IntRect(0, 0, 2, 10));
```

This line has some syntax errors in itself, but it is not loading the texture in the right place anyways.

First you need to initialize a static class variable somewhere, usually in the cpp file for that class.

```
// In your header for Lovedek
class Lovedek
{
    ...
    static sf::Texture texture;    // Declare the static texture
    ...
};

// In your cpp file for Lovedek

sf::Texture Lovedek::texture;   // Initialize the static texture
```

Then think about *when* you want to load the texture, probably near the beginning of your `main` function, or in some sort of setup function right?

You can either make `Lovedek::texture` public and load the texture outside the class, or you can keep it private and implement something like a `LoadAssets()` static method to do that.

For the public approach:

```
// Make Lovedek::texture a public class member

// Then put this somewhere in your game's setup (before starting the game loop)

Lovedek::texture.loadFromFile("bullet_graphics.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 2, 10));
```

For the private approach:

```
// Change your Lovedek class
class Lovedek
{
    static sf::Texture texture;
public:
    static void LoadAssets()
    {
        texture.loadFromFile("bullet_graphics.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 2, 10));
    }
}

// Then put this somewhere in your game's setup (before starting the game loop)

Lovedek::LoadAssets();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've actually tried doing your private approach, I only missed the initializing line from the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `static` and classes here. What you want is a namespace:

```
namespace Lovedek
{
    sf::Texture texture;
}
```

So yeah, it's basically a global variable. Generally bad design, but if you need an object that is accessible from anywhere, you might already do it correctly (with a namespace). Now you can load that outside:

```
Lovedek::texture.loadFromFile("bullet_graphics.png",sf::IntRect(0, 0, 2, 10));
```

so the information is saved into `Lovedek::texture`. When you now want to apply that to an `sf::Sprite` just go:

```
sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.setTexture(Lovedek::texture);
```

It's very straightforward usage. A "pure static class" would be very against the idea of how classes generally should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I'm only a beginner at c++, I'd rather not mess around with namespaces just yet

Comment: @Bende a namespace doesn't do anything. It just adds `Lovedek::` before the name. The benefit is that the variable is global, so you can access it from anywhere in the code.

Comment: @StackDanny Declaring it as a private static class member is a safer and cleaner design if only that class needs the texture though. A global texture could be modified by other code.

Comment: @Romen well ok, *private* static members: in that case, yes, absolutely. But as OP had it with a public static member I had to disagree. But sure - I can see how a private static texture makes sense!